# find a parameter such that a transformation matrix is isomorphism

Tags: calculus

I have a matrix below and I want to find $k$ such that this matrix becomes isomorphism. What should I do exactly? We are not allowed to use determinant! should we find $k$ such that this matrix is not invertible and if so how?

$$A=\left(\begin{array}{r;r;r;r}
 -1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 2-k & 0 & 3\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 4-k
\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: a function is an isomorphism if $f(x)=y$  has exactly one solution for each $y$. If $f$ is linear it is sufficient to show that $f(x)=0$ has exactly one solution. This solution is 0 of course. So try to show that Ax=0 has only the solution 0.

Comment: What do you know about the rank of a matrix and how that relates to $f(x)=Ax$ being injective?